# Using find command

Tags: osx, grep, find

I have a bunch of directories. Inside these directories is a cover letter and a zip archive of work. I wanted to run a quick and easy query to open up all the cover letters so I can decide if it's worth looking at the work folder.

```
find . | grep cover\.pdf | xargs open    #OS X has open linked to "open" the file
```

This doesn't work. I've also muddied around with various `print0`, `xargs -0` variations with little success. What's the proper way to do this?

Comment: "this doesn't work" translates to? nothing happening? an error message? your computer catching fire?

Comment: removed the "unix" tag, isn't everything unix already?

Comment: @phu Well, there are [24 other posts tagged [unix\]](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unix). It might end up getting blacklisted if it's so abused as to become useless, but we probably won't discuss that for a little while

Comment: @hop: It doesn't perform as expected, nothing gets opened.

Comment: Can you give us an ls -l of one of the directories that has the files you are looking for in please?  I'm curious to find out why this isn't working.

Answer (score 3):

First, always check what versions of `find`/`xargs` you actually use on your Mac-OSX box. Perhaps you expect BSD/GNU behavior/options and use GNU/BSD versions.

Don't know if *open* supports multiple arguments. If not call `xargs` like this:

```
xargs -n 1 open
```

(which means that xargs executes for every argument an extra open process)

And keep in mind that `find | xargs` without `-print0/-0` is expected to fail if your filenames/paths contain spaces.

Aha, if you use something like

```
find -print0 | grep something | xargs -0 foo
```

then `grep` is confused by all the `\0` characters.

GNU `grep` (at least) knows the `-z` option. Thus, which should work is:

```
find -print0 | grep -z something | xargs -0 foo
```

Check what `grep` version you use via

```
grep --version
```

Or check the man page of your `grep` for `\0` (zero character) support.

Comment: This works better, but appending `-print0` gives me an output of `binary file matches` in grep.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
find . -name cover\.pdf -exec open '{}' \;
```

You can test like this:

```
find . -name cover\.pdf -exec ls -l '{}' \;
```

Not sure what the man page looks like on OSX, but there are various examples in the find man page, if you search for EXAMPLES.  I often find myself refreshing my brain by checking those.

Comment: I don't have an OSX box handy to test on though, so... it may not!

Comment: @gabe: This doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Tried it on a mac, and seems like the general case works... if you do the ls -l version above, what output do you get?

Comment: @gabe's suggestion totally works on OS X 10.6.  I suspect you typed it wrong or something.

Comment: use `'{}' +` not `'{}' \;` the + has better optimization...

Comment: @Sansy: "typed it wrong or something" – Please define the "or something" because I'm not typing it wrong. Nothing gets opened, nothing gets outputted. Nothing gets outputted when running `find . -name cover\.jpg` either.

Comment: @Josh: if you do `touch xyzzy; find . -name xyzzy -ls; rm xyzzy` do you get any output?

Comment: @Dennis: Yes, I get the xyzzy file.

Comment: @JoshK: Then if `find . -name cover\.pdf` doesn't output anything then there's no file by that name under that directory.

Comment: @xenoterracide Only use `{} +` if the utility makes proper sense of multiple arguments. And don't quote the `{}`.

Answer (score 1):

If your xargs on your system supports -n option you can try following.

`find . | grep cover\.pdf | xargs -n 1 open`